# Swagger / Open API - Validate request against swagger schema depending on users request body parameter

Tags: amazon-web-services, swagger, openapi

I have some difficulties with OAS3 (swagger) validation. I am trying to build up project which uses AWS API gateway defined by swagger file. In this project users can upload a documents. Before incoming document is stored, I need to process some validation depending on value of request body parameter *documentType*. Is there some possibility in OAS for dynamic schema validation? I have a request like this:

### User request:

```
POST: documents/
```

with request body like this:

```
{
   "key1":"value1",
   "key2":"value2",
   "documentType":"x",
   "data":{
       "foo":"valueA",
       "bar":"valueB"
    }
}
```

## Problematics

I need to define swagger validation for data object depending on given documentType value. Lets say documentType is x so I need to validate data object against schema x. If documentType is y, validate it against schema y, and so on. I also need handle default situation when given documentType does't have its validator. In this case I want to return bad request error. Can OAS achieve this? If so, how?

## Possible solution

```
paths:
  /documents:
    post:
      requestBody:
        content:
          application/json:
            schema:
              oneOf:
                - $ref: '#/components/schemas/DocType1'
                - $ref: '#/components/schemas/DocType2'
      responses:
        '200':
          description: Updated
components:
  schemas:
    DocType1:
      type: object
      properties:
        key1:
          type: string
        key2:
          type: string
        documentType:
          type: string
          enum: [x]
        data:
          properties:
            foo:
              type: string
            bar:
              type: string
    DocType2:
      type: object
      properties:
        key1:
          type: string
        key2:
          type: string
        documentType:
          type: string
          enum: [y]
        data:
          properties:
            baz:
              type: string
            qux:
              type: string
```

This is my idea how it could works, but I do not like it. I see there problems when request body becomes large, even if this solution can be simplified via refs. I hope there is a clear solution but still beyond my grasp.

Comment: Does your validation library/framework support [`discriminator`](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/3.0.2.md#discriminator-object)? If yes, you probably just need to add the `discriminator` alongside `oneOf`.

Comment: Thanks for response, but unfortunately aws does not support discriminator according to [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-known-issues.html) page.